# Very poor working of Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to do just a simple users loading in select 2 using AJAX. My code is as simple as:

```
$('.loadUsers').select2({
        placholder: "Test placeholder",
        minimumInputLength: 2

});
```

Now the first problem is the placeholder is not even working (nothing is displayed, no error at all) but the select2 input is displayed properly. Moreover, when I try to add the `ajax` option to select2 parameters I get the following error:

```
Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
```

How to solve these problems?

The version of Select2 I'm using is 3.2.

// EDIT

Ok, I somehow managed to fix the AJAX loading by assigning the select2 to a hidden input instead of a select and adding both `data` and `results` properties. However the placeholder is still not showing. Why?

Comment: because mis-spelling.

Comment: Wow, so much looking at it and I just couldn't notice it, thanks :-)